# Castle.Services.Transaction upgrade from 2.5 to 3.0.2 issues

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, castle-windsor, castle

I am trying to upgrade Castle.Windsor lib from 2.5.3 to 5.0.1. I could figure out the deprecated properties, methods and could upgrade the Windsor to newer version but ran into runtime error. So I figured out that I have to upgrade **Castle.Services.Transaction** from 2.5 to 3.0.2 as well.
I am new to this lib and not sure of the replacements of the deprecated methods and interfaces in the old common code of the project.
Its all about the transaction,session and syncronization and that part is always risky in the project.
I have gone through the github repository of https://github.com/castleproject but unable to understand the replacements.
We already have upgraded Castle.Core from 2.5.2 to 4.4.1
I understand the I may have to also upgrade Castle.Facilities.AutoTx from 2.5.1 to 3.2.2.

Any guidance for below issues will be very helpful.

[image: screnshot of errors]

1. what is the replacement of IResource [image]
2. Can I replace DefaultTransactionManager with TransactionManager safely?   [image] with [image]
3. How to replace 'ISynchronization' with ISinglePhaseNotification [image]
4. What is the replacement for SessionDisposeSynchronization[image]
5. WHat is the replacement for IsolationLevel  [image]
6. What are the replacements for ITransaction, Context, Enlist, RegisterSynchronization,IsAmbient [image]
   Please help.